# Can't SetUndecorated even if frame is setVisible(false)

Tags: java, swing, jframe

In my application from a button <kbd>See</kbd> I display a jframe (undecorated, MAXIMIZED_BOTH, Visible and alwaysOnTop) then after some time when I am done working on it, I set it invisible from a button <kbd>Close</kbd> on that frame itself... But after that, when I again click the button to display the jframe, it says `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: The frame is displayable.` even tough I have set the frame invisible.

Is this much information is sufficient or do you need more?

**Update:**
My main file is `FormTTS.java` I also have a file named `FTDirect.java`, which has 3 frames: `See`, `Blank` and `Main`. In the Main frame I have a button <kbd>See</kbd> which makes the see frame visible, in the see frame after my work I make itself invisible from a button in itself and then I get returned to the main frame. Now if I again click the <kbd>See</kbd> button I get the error

**Code:**
<kbd>See</kbd> button in Main frame in FTDirect.java

```
See.setUndecorated(true);
See.setVisible(true);
See.setAlwaysOnTop(rootPaneCheckingEnabled);
See.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
......
```

<kbd>Close</kbd> button in See Frame in FTDirect.java

```
this.setVisible(false); //That's it
```

**Minimal example program**
(Pseudocodes)

**File: FormTTS.java**

```
FTdirect directform = new FTdirect();
directform.setVisible(true);
directform.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

**File: FTDirect.java**

```
//Main frame
private void MainSeeButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    See.setUndecorated(true);
    See.setVisible(true);
    See.setAlwaysOnTop(rootPaneCheckingEnabled);
    See.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
}
//See frame - Close Button
private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    See.setVisible(false);
}
```

**So concluding**: I click the see button I get the See frame in there I click the close button it becomes invisible and now if I click the see button again it gives an error

Comment: I don't think that your posted text is adequate to allow us to understand your problem enough to answer it. If you don't get a decent answer soon, consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: We can't run nor compile the posted code. We can not test it for problems, nor experience the problems ourselves. Again, please consider creating and posting a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok, I will just try to do that...

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels How is it now?

Comment: Have you gone through the link that I've given you? Here it is for a 3rd time: [minimal complete example program link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please read it as it will help both you and us greatly.

Comment: @DakshShah Why are you calling `See.setUndecorated(true);` again from `See` button? just removing this line will solve your problem.

Comment: @Braj I wanted it to be undecorated I can't tell whether I am clicking the button for first time or second. So where to put `See.setUndecorated(true);` then?

Comment: use `isUndecorated()` method first to check for it.,

Comment: @Braj Sorry I dint get you, what kind of flag? Also, I tried putting the code in constructor but it does not work

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I read that post and I will always keep that in mind while framing a question, thanks for your help :)

Comment: there are another possible states that generated IllegalComponentStateException not only ....

Comment: @mKorbel Could you please write an answer explaining the another possibility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify code for <kbd>See</kbd> method using [Frame#isUndecorated()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#isUndecorated%28%29) that Indicates whether this frame is undecorated. By default, all frames are initially decorated.

```
if (!See.isUndecorated()) {
    See.setUndecorated(true);
}
if(!See.isVisible()){
    See.setVisible(true);
}
See.setAlwaysOnTop(rootPaneCheckingEnabled);
See.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```